# How to map EnumSet (or List of Enums) in an entity using JPA2

Tags: mapping, entity, enumset

I have entity Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="", name="PERSON")
public class Person {
    List<PaymentType> paymentTypesList;
    //some other fields     
    //getters and setters and other logic
}
```

and I have enum PaymentType:

```
public enum PaymentType {
    FIXED, CO_FINANCED, DETERMINED;
}
```

How to persist Person and its list of enums (in this list I have to place variable amount of enums, there may be one of them, or two or all of them)

I'm using Spring with Postgres, Entity are created using JPA annotation, and managed using Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself, wheter `PaymentType`s can change over time.

I would create a `@Entity PaymentType` with one name attribute, and create a `@Many2Many` between `PaymentType` and `Person`.

Another approach: `@ElementCollection`
See [ElementCollection from From Wikibooks, the open-content textbooks collection](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection)